# Place a Jenkins Job inside a folder using Jenkins Job Builder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to create a Jenkins Job inside a folder using Jenkins Job Builder,
no luck so far ;(

The following creates the job and the folder, but the job is not inside the folder ;(

Please help

contents of rest-framework.yaml

```
- job:
name: folder_test
project-type: folder
primary-view: project_view
health-metrics:
  - worst-child-health-metric

- view:
name: project_view
view-type: list
folder: true
columns:
    - status
    - weather
    - job
    - last-success
    - last-failure
    - last-duration
regex: (?!rest-framework.*).*

- job-template:
name: '{name}-hello-world'
builders:
  - shell: 'echo "hello world!"'

- project:
name: rest-framework
jobs:
  - '{name}-hello-world'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to place the job you created in a folder, make sure the name at the project level or the job level includes the folder.

Example:

```
- job-template:
 name: '{name}-hello-world'
builders:
  - shell: 'echo "hello world!"'

- project:
name: folder_test/rest-framework
jobs:
 - '{name}-hello-world'
```

This snippet *requires* the folder to already be created (which you did above, but cut it off here for simplicity).

Edited: Removed original response saying it isn't possible, but I did more testing to find a solution using Jenkins-Jobs-Builder 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
- job:
    name: 'end2endTestJobs'
    project-type: folder
- job-template:
    name: 'this-is-my-job-name'
    folder: "end2endTestJobs"
- project:
    name: my-project-name
    jobs:
      - this-is-my-job-name
```

https://jenkins-job-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project_folder.html?highlight=project